# How to get updateProfile in Firebase.dart to work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am new to flutter and I can't get firebase updateProfile function work

I created a user through the console and tried to update the user info through code in flutter web application.
I created userprofile instance:

```
UserProfile fbP = UserProfile();
fbP.displayName = "Youmna";
fbP.photoURL = "";
```

And passed it to updateProfile function:

```
authFB.currentUser.updateProfile(fbP);
```

--authFB is my Firebase.Auth attribute

And I reloaded the user

```
authFB.currentUser.reload();
```

And then I tried to print the display name, but it gave me null!

```
print(authFB.currentUser.displayName);
```

However I tried to print the email and it printed it correctly.

```
print(authFB.currentUser.email);
```

What shall I do, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you have missed `async`/`await` keywords.
Use them as in this example:

```dart
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;

...

  void updateProfile() async {
    final profile = fb.UserProfile();
    profile.displayName = 'Another Name';
    profile.photoURL = '';
    final user = fb.auth().currentUser;
    await user.updateProfile(profile);
    await user.reload();
    print(user.displayName);
  }
```